# Java: using typed variables in a generic class

Tags: java, generics, compilation

Could someone please explain to me why this piece of code does not compile?

Even though it uses a generic class without providing the specific type T, it should be able to recognize at compile time that the ArrayList holds strings.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Container container = new Container();
        container.strings.add("test");
        String s1 = container.strings.get(0); // does not compile
        ArrayList<String> local = container.strings;
        String s2 = local.get(0); // does compile
    }

    static class Container <T>{
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't think the compilation error may be helpful in figuring out why it does not compile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use a generic class as a raw type (one where you don't specify a type), **ALL generic information is stripped from the class** (whether the omitted type is used or not).

So when you code `Container container` (instead of `Container<SomeClass> container`) `ArrayList<String> strings` becomes `ArrayList strings`, which is used as if it were `ArrayList<Object>`.

To "fix", specify the type for `Container` (even though you don't use the type):

```
Container<Object> container = new Container<Object>();
```

the rest will now compile.

---

The reason this is done is to be backward compatible with earlier pre-generic versions of java (1.4 and earlier)

Comment: That sounds a bit extreme... any idea why they decided to make it that way?

Comment: @K-ballo: Because Java generics were glued on as an afterthought and at runtime everything is `Object`. Generics only really do their thing at compile time.

Comment: @Bohemian: I still don't see why that calls for stripping a concrete type that is not related to the generics parameter, but hey... afterthought :P

Comment: @K-ballo it is severe, and it can lead to some hard to find bugs, but that's java for you - strict

Comment: *Backword compatibility* means that legacy code is still compilable and doesn't break at runtime, but I can't find a way how not erasing types in a raw type would bring to failure

Comment: @Raffaele It's the other way around... it's so things don't break when legacy code calls modern (generic) code.

Comment: @Bohemian actually it is the *only* way things would break, because newer code can't use *raw types* from legacy libraries written before generics came out. I can't understand the point of this spec, but since you got it, would you make an example?

Comment: @Raffaele Google gave me these SO links: [this brief one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501444) and [this authoritative one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321)

Comment: I appreciate your research, but still consider this decision sort of a *glitch*. Erasing only types parameterized using the *T* parameter would have been a wiser choice to me, it would have provided reasonable interop and more expected results, because the kind of avoided breakages is still not avoidable when the new version of a library uses generics without parameterizing its own types

Comment: @Raffaele I definitely understand your point of view and probably agree.

Comment: ;) what hat are you running for?

Answer (score 0):

As Bohemian said, every type argument in a raw type is thrown away. At the beginning I thought it was a bug, but there's even an entry in the [bug database (#6244346)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=d98d58bc0945e8e8433f9f2e179?bug_id=6244346) which explicitely quotes the relevant [JLS §4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or
> non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from
> its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds
> to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to
> C.
>
> The type of a static method or static field of a raw type C is the
> same as its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.
>
> It is a compile-time error to pass type arguments to a non-static type
> member of a raw type that is not inherited from its superclasses or
> superinterfaces.
>
> It is a compile-time error to attempt to use a type member of a
> parameterized type as a raw type.

The reason why you can't get a `String` from a raw `List`, but you can assign a `List` to a `List<String>` is because in the latter the compiler issues a warning (*unchecked conversion*) but you don't report it (do you read warnings, don't you? :P). I tested your code with javac and the Eclipse compiler, and both honor the spec.

Raw types were introduced for interoperability with legacy code, but in this case I can't figure out a way how keeping type information for non-static members would have break things. Using a parameterized type instead of a raw type would mean *code partially ported*, so maybe in this case the purpose is not simply backcompat, but ensuring a coherent codebase, either the code is full 1.4, or it's entirely Java 5+. Another option is that using raw types like this may have slowed down the adoption of unbounded wildcards in similar contexts.

BTW (but I think you figured it out by yourself) you can simply use an unbounded wildcard if you don't use the type parameter, ie `Container<?>`